# Code instrumentation in haskell

Tags: haskell, instrumentation

Suppose I maintain complex application connected to external systems. One day it starts to return unexpected results for certain input and I need to find out why. It could be DNS problem, filesytem related problem, external system change, anything.

Assuming that amount of processing is extensive, before I can identify possible locations of the problem I would need to obtain detailed traces which original application does not produce.

How can I instrument existing code so that I can (for example) provide non-volatile proof (not a live debug session) that certain component or function has a bug.

Comment: I don't totally follow you, but [ekg](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ekg) is a pretty awesome tool, and lets you set arbitrary counters and values in `IO`.

Comment: @jberryman Sounds like this would make a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like more of an architecture/best practices type question than anything Haskell-specific, unless I'm misunderstanding something.

It sounds like your application needs to use a logging system, such as [hslogger](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hslogger).  The general approach is to have each component of your code create logging messages with an attached priority.  You can then have the application handle different priority levels differently, so for example critical errors could be displayed on the console, while debug and info-level errors go to logfiles.

It's sometimes useful to use `Debug.Trace.traceEvent` and `Debug.Trace.traceEventIO` instead of a logging system, particularly if you suspect a concurrency issue, as the ghc eventlog also logs information about thread spawning/switching and garbage collection.  But in general it's not a substitution for an actual logging framework.

Also, you may want to make use of `assert` as a sanity check that "impossible" conditions really don't occur.